# Can I have CollectionProperty inside of a Custom Property Class?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a custom property group class that would have a reference to collection that stores custom properties of a specific type. Is that even possible with Python and Blender?

The basic trivial example to illustrate what I am after could be this:

A book has pages. So I want an object of type BOOK to have a reference to a collection of objects of type PAGE.

Thank you so much for any comments and suggestions!

A sample code that doesn't work at the moment:

[image]

```
import bpy
    
class Page(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    content_of_the_page: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Content",
        description="Content of the page", 
        default="",
    )
           
class Book(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    title: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="Title",
        description="The title of the book", 
        default="",
    )
    
    pages: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type = Page)
    

def register():
    
    bpy.utils.register_class(Book)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Page)

    bpy.types.Scene.books = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type = Book)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Book)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Page)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: In the `register` function, put `bpy.utils.register_class(Page)` first. Then `bpy.utils.register_class(Book)`. In the order you have it now, it won't work, because Blender doesn't know the class `Page` yet.

Comment: Omg....of course....Thank you so much, that was a rookie mistake on my end. Thank you thank you thank you!